# How to find if QuickBooks desktop application opened or not against any company file through C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, quickbooks

I have a `C#` application communicate with my `QuickBooks` Desktop application's company file to perform CRUD (employee) operation in both `C#` and `QuickBooks` applications.

Here, I need to check whether `QuickBooks` desktop application is open or not and prompt valid message box for users that "You need to open QuickBooks application before perform CURD operation". Since, as per standard provided by `QuickBooks SDK`, need to open the `QuickBooks` before perform CRUD. Without to do so, my application thrown COM object error.

I have used `QuickBooks SDK 13.0, Microsoft Visual Studio 13 (.Net Framework 4.5), C#`.

Please help to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: You could list the processes running, and see if the expected .exe is running, but you're subject to changes in the name of the other .exe, and if the application runs with another user's account, you might not be able to.